# Bash script error: bad fd number

Tags: bash, file-descriptor

I'm using a script to modify some mailboxes on a Zimbra server hosted on a Ubuntu server. This script checks if mailbox exists and, if so, proceeds the required change.

I get the error

```
scriptname.sh: 4: Syntax error: Bad fd number
```

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
email=$1
echo "Looking for $email"
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmprov ga "$email" displayName > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Mailbox not found on this server"; exit 2;
fi
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmprov ModifyAccount "$email" zimbraMailTransport smtp:server.domain.com:25
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error updating Transport.";                                                     
    exit 3;
fi
echo "Transport updated";
```

The error is related to this line:

```
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmprov ga "$email" displayName > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I'm quite a newbie on bash, so.. I don't really know how to debug this.

Comment: If i'm right, fd means File Descriptor.

Comment: run it with `bash -x scriptname.sh`, it will echo each command before executing it, you will most probably spot the problem straight away

Comment: Thanks bobah, I got it with you command. For an unknown reason, a \r was added at the end of each line of the script.. Removed it with notepad++, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

For an unknown reason, a \r was added at the end of each line of the script.. Removed it with notepad++, and it worked like a charm. – Ashina